# Download all wiki pages

Tags: ros, offline, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to download the entire wiki as a PDF document or collection of HTML pages in order to allow offline viewing? It is possible to create a PDF of a single page using the drop-down menu on the right of each page, but this doesn't appear to include the linked content within the wiki, so it would be a long process to do this manually for each page (and it would lose the structure).

thanks,

Nick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9455/download-all-wiki-pages/) by [hawesie](https://answers.ros.org/users/246/hawesie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 282 on 2011-03-16

Post score: 9

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://www.ros.org/wiki_dump/ doesn't exist any longer, instead rsync as described in http://wiki.ros.org/Mirrors#Setup_rsync:

```
rsync -azv rsync.osuosl.org::ros_wiki_mirror wiki.ros.org --bwlimit=200 --delete
```

It will download many files into a directory `wiki.ros.org`, currently totals 1.45GB.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                      R S Y N C . O S U O S L . O R G
                          Oregon State University
                              Open Source Lab

       Unauthorized use is prohibited - violators will be prosecuted
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

                For more information about the OSL visit:
                    http://osuosl.org/services/hosting

          This host is the home to the primary archives of several
           projects.  We would prefer that only primary/secondary
                    mirrors use this service.  Thanks!

---------------------------------------------------------------------------


receiving incremental file list
...
attachments/Events(2f)CoTeSys(2d)ROS(2d)School(2f)Presentations/
attachments/Events(2f)CoTeSys(2d)ROS(2d)School(2f)Presentations/mkrainin_intro_slides.pptx
...
```

Once it is done open wiki.ros.org/Documentation.html in a browser

(looks like the rsync host was changed in 2017 from ros.org to OSU http://wiki.ros.org/action/info/Mirrors?action=diff&rev2=94&rev1=93 - the 'we would prefer' wording above makes it seem like they don't want random people making personal archives though?)

from
http://answers.ros.org/question/10010/create-a-rosorg-wiki-mirror/

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2014-10-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can get an HTML tarball here:

http://www.ros.org/wiki_dump/

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-03-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hawesie](https://answers.ros.org/users/246/hawesie/) on 2011-03-21**:
Cool, thanks.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-03-18**:
Great! I took the liberty to mirror both on http://ros.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-03-17**:
roswiki is the wiki pages, doc is the doxygen/epydoc/other API docs.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-03-17**:
Very cool. What is the difference between roswiki.tar.gz and doc.tar.gz?